# Add custom ServerMux to a http.Handle

Tags: go

I am creating a module which will provide a `http.Handler` that can be attached to any running server.

My module has a lot of bundled  `handlerFunc`s for handling internal requests:

```
func NewHandler() http.Handler {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/one", func(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
        writer.Write([]byte("one"))
    })
    mux.HandleFunc("/two", func(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
        writer.Write([]byte("two"))
    })
    return mux
}
```

This handler can be attached to a custom path:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/someuser/someproject"
)

func main() {
    http.Handle("/path", someproject.NewHandler())
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

On request invocation to `http://localhost:8080/path/one` I get `404`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are missing the / at the end of path.. You need to [strip the path prefix](https://godoc.org/net/http#StripPrefix) passed to `NewHandler`.   `http.Handle("/path/", http.StripPrefix("/path/", someproject.NewHandler())`

Comment: @CeriseLimón `http.Handle("/path/", http.StripPrefix("/path/", someproject.NewHandler()))`, the request redirects to `localhost:8080/one` and I get `404`. Also I can't remove base path and have a redirect to endpoint `/one` on root, because it can be already used by the host server for something else if someone uses my module.

Comment: What happens if you strip only `"/path"`?

Comment: @mkopriva Yes, thank you, that worked. Having `http.Handle("/path/", http.StripPrefix("/path", someproject.NewHandler()))` works as expected. Request return 200 without redirects and does not interfere if I define with the endpoint `http.HandleFunc("/one", ...` on the server

Comment: See [How to combine two (or more) http.ServeMux?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43380025/5728991).  Possible duplicate?