# Nested http.ServeMux that can handle path without trailing slash

Tags: go, servemux

Consider the example below. This example is an evolution from [this Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43380025/3634032) answer where a nested `http.ServeMux` is used to handle requests under a given path:

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    rootMux := http.NewServeMux()
    rootMux.Handle("/", writeHandler("root mux"))
    rootMux.Handle("/top_path/", http.StripPrefix("/top_path", subHandler()))

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", rootMux)
}

func subHandler() http.Handler {
    subMux := http.NewServeMux()
    subMux.Handle("/", writeHandler("sub mux"))
    subMux.Handle("/sub_path", writeHandler("sub path"))
    return subMux
}

func writeHandler(message string) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte(message))
    })
}
```

When running this example and sending a request to `localhost:8080`, you will get `root mux` in the response, as you would expect. When making a request to `localhost:8080/top_path` (without the trailing slash), you will also get the expected response of `sub mux`. The one difference this time however is that the request was actually redirected to `localhost:8080/top_path/` (with a trailing slash).

This trailing-slash redirection behavior is described in the [http package documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#hdr-Trailing_slash_redirection).

So my question is this: Is there no way to have a nested mux, such as `subMux` that can handle both `top_path` (without trailing slash **and no redirect**) and anything under it, e.g. `/top_path/sub_path`? If `rootMux` is able to handle requests to `localhost:8080` without redirecting to `localhost:8080/`, then shouldn't there be a way for `subMux` to be able to handle requests to `localhost:8080/top_path` without redirecting to `localhost:8080/top_path/`?

Comment: And you does not want to register other`rootMux.Handle("/top_path", subHandler())` ? (docs: `This behavior can be overridden with a separate registration for the path without the trailing slash or "..." wildcard. For example, registering "/images/" causes ServeMux to redirect a request for "/images" to "/images/", unless "/images" has been registered separately.`)

Comment: Regarding "rootMux is able to handle requests to localhost:8080 without redirecting": Because HTTP request lines must always include a path, requests for localhost:8080 *do* in fact include a slash. It is just added automatically by your client for your convenience.